# JS: add a variable as a property (.) with (+)

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop

If I am trying to add a variable as a property I get the error:

`"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token +"`

So basically I am trying to add a variable from a loop as a property to JSON like this:

```
   var tables = ["table1", "table2", "table3"];
   for (var x = 0; x < tables.length; x++) {
     var item = $database. + tables[x];
     console.log(item);
   }
```

If i use (") like this
`var item = "$database." + tables[x];`

It works, but it becomes a string (if that's the proper name) so I can not view the JSON objects.

Why is this happening and Is this even possible to do?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps your mean `$database[tables[x]]` but without context it's hard to say. Depends on what `$database` is.

Comment: Use bracket notation if you need to pass the property name as a string. So something like `var item = $database[tables[x]];`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (var x = 0; x < tables.length; x++) {
    var item = $database[tables[x]];
    console.log(item);
}
```

If your `$database` is dynamic and you don't want to have a hard-coded array of table names, you can also use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```
var tables = Object.keys($database);
```

Comment: Wow! 99+ for the "Object.keys()" That's so useful!  Thanks! :D

Answer (score 5):

you can use bracket notation:

```
for (var x = 0; x < tables.length; x++) {
    var item = $database[tables[x]];
    console.log(item);
 }
```